# How to select a first and last element which does not contain the class hidden

Tags: html, css

I like to perform a selection of the first and last element which does not contain the class hidden.

```
   <div class="gallery-cell hidden"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell hidden"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell hidden"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell hidden"></div>
```

**This works for me to catch all elements.**

But how do I get only the first and last?

```
.gallery-cell:not(.hidden){
    opacity:0.2 !important;
}
```

Pure css would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

This is unfortunately not possible in CSS only, because `first-child`, `last-child`, and `nth-of-type` all don't accomplish quite what we're looking for. Following is a JavaScript solution.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var notHidden = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery-cell:not(.hidden)");
notHidden[0].classList.add("targeted");
notHidden[notHidden.length - 1].classList.add("targeted");
```

```css
.gallery-cell {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 10px;
}

.targeted {
    opacity:0.2 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-cell hidden"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell hidden"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell hidden"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell hidden"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the first one using the adjacent sibling selector (+) with a `:not()` pseudo-class selector like this: `.gallery-cell.hidden+:not(.hidden)`. I don't have a solution for "last-before..."

```css
.gallery-cell {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.hidden {
  background-color: blue;
}

.gallery-cell.hidden+:not(.hidden){ /* <- This will catch first non-hidden */
  border: 2px green solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-cell hidden"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell hidden"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell hidden"></div>
<div class="gallery-cell hidden"></div>
```